# Use Context.xml to store dynamic variable value

Tags: jsp, tomcat

In my webapp, I must use the `context.xml` to register a variable which is to be used in a JSP. For example, a variable `X` with the value `"xfromcontext"`, so that I can print it in JSP as `out.println(X)`. How do I get the `X`'s value from `context.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify an `<Environment>` entry which does exactly the same as regular `<env-entry>` in `web.xml`.

E.g.

```
<Environment name="X" value="xfromcontext" type="java.lang.String" />
```

which is obtainable (in servlet) by

```
String X = (String) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/X");
// ...
```

I'd suggest to read it once and store it in the application scope on webapp's startup. You can use a `ServletContextListener` for this. Then you can just access it in JSP by `${X}`. Doing a `out.println()` in JSP is a rather old school way which has been discouraged over a decade ago.

Comment: it can't find symbol the InitialContext() , is it any imports?

Comment: It's this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/naming/InitialContext.html