# I want to read the parameters of tomcat context.xml

Tags: java, tomcat

I want to get companyName value which is in context.xml
I am getting `null` value after writing the code mentioned below

Please help me in getting the value from `context.xml`. You can even tell other way of getting value from `context.xml`

**NOTE : Don't say to write param in `web.xml`**

**Context.xml (Tomcat 7)**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

    <!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
         on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
    -->
<Parameter name="companyName" value="My Company, Incorporated"
          override="false"/> 

</Context>
```

**JSP(index.jsp)**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
ServletContext sc= getServletContext();
String testNameValue = sc.getInitParameter("companyName");
%>
<input type="text" value="<%=testNameValue%>">
</body>
</html>
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Updated after implementing the solution given below**

*Exception comes*

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW7Fz.png)

Comment: Which value are you trying to get again?  And what isn't working?  Try to create an [MCVE]

Comment: I can't reproduce with the exact same code on tomcat 8

Comment: in Tomcat there is an context.xml,  In that i have one parameter as companyName with some value ..In jsp i want that value but i am not getting the correct value ,  i am getting null as value , Please use tomcat 7

Comment: Posible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271343/use-context-xml-to-store-dynamic-variable-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot load that way because `context.xml` is JNDI resource. Please try the following approach:

***Tomcat (context.xml)***

`<Parameter name="companyName" value="My Company, Incorporated" override="false"/>`

***Java Side***

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
Context xmlNode = (Context) context.lookup("java:comp/env");
String companyName = (String) xmlNode.lookup("companyName");
```

***Spring Side***
HomeController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView mav) throws Exception {
        String companyName = servletContext.getInitParameter("companyName");
        mav.setViewName("home/index");
        mav.addObject("companyName", companyName);
        return mav;
    }

    public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.servletContext = servletContext;
    }
}
```

***View Side***
index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <c:out value="${companyName}"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above example has proven successful on my end. My script can read from `context.xml` file at runtime as shown.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [companyName] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [companyName].
 org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912) ...... for more see uploded pic above in question

Comment: This is spring MVC I want to do with simple web app that to using scriplets in jsp . If u can help . Thankx

Comment: You've made a mistake. This is not "<Parameter ...>" but "<Environment ...>" !! If we specify "<Parameter..." we need to access differently to the variable : config.getServletContext().getInitParameter("companyName").

Comment: This answer is not correct as per the comment by @Laurent.B

Answer (score 4):

```
<Environment name="companyName" value="My Company, Incorporated" 
type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

worked better for me than **Parameter** because the latter was throwing 
 `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [companyName] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [companyName].` when trying to get the value using `String companyName = (String) xmlNode.lookup("companyName");`

Comment: What is the difference between the `<Parameter>` and `<Environment>` elements? Environment seems to work but Parameter doesn't for me in Tomcat 8